# Parsing Json in Jquery returning NULL

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse a json string in Jquery but its returning me null 
I am using simple `jQuery.parseJSON`
Here is what i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonStr);
    alert(obj);
});
```

but the alert says null
Here is the fiddle with actual json http://jsfiddle.net/9kw99L2h/

Comment: that is already an object. you don't need to parse it. `parseJSON` takes a string.

Comment: @DanielA.White how can i use this json to extract values from it ?

Comment: using an indexer `object['key']` or dot-notation `object.key`

Comment: Since it's an object already, you can navigate it's properties using, for example, `jsonStr.hierarch.folder["@name"]` (yields `Root` in your example)

Comment: Good to know. I've made an answer with a longer explanation. Unless someone comes with a better or more helpful one, mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing your json as:

```
var json = { "hierarch": {
    'date':"2014/08/25 20:23:43",
    "folder":{
        "@name":"Root",
        "@id":"Root"}
        } 
    }
}
```

Since it's an object already, you can navigate it's properties using, for example:

```
jsonStr.hierarch.folder["@name"] // yields Root
```

`JSON.parse`, or `jQuery.parseJSON` is only useful when you have a string in json format:

```
var jsonStr = "{ key: 'value' }";
console.log(jsonStr.key); // logs undefined. Strings does not contain property named key.
var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(json.key); // logs value
```